# Sticky header with next and previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a sticky header with next and previous button in my site.
Initially there is no sticky section but when the user scrolls down the menu hides into a hamburger menu and the sticky element comes up. On further scrolling the sub section titles like Features, Contact Us, etc... are updated .Also we we can goto next and previous section as shown in the image.

So, how do I build this or is there a plugin that I can make use of?
Thank you.

Comment: Show your code effort.

Answer (score 0):

## Sticky Things

Sticky sections can be achieved using a combination of regular HTML, regular CSS and a Javascript plugin [like sticky.js here](http://stickyjs.com/). Using it you can use JS to attach a `CSS` class to certain `HTML` sections when a visitor is scrolling.
You can then style the `CSS`accordingly to display / or hide certain sections of the page on scroll and thereby override / rewrite the original positioning.

## Previous and Next

To achieve a previous and next button you could link those manually using HTML as well - which would be quite some work. If you look for dynamically linke site content you should have a look at static site generators like **Octopress**, or **Jekyll** - or consider using a CMS like **Wordpress**.

***Edit:** If you mean "jumping" up and down from one section of the site to another you can look at HTML `anchor links`*

I have done a sticky header and a previous / next button in the footer for my website using **Jekyll** with some manual modifications. You can have a look at [my blog on Github](https://github.com/dyscribe/dyscribe_blog) to see how I solved it.

Besides this it is not easy as there is not default solution to what you are trying to do. It fairly depends on your constraints, preferences and skills.

Comment: Thanks for solution. I'll try implementing it and let you know. Yes, I want to jump from one section to another but by using javascript or jquery.